How I can associate my request with my response at the responseMiddleware?
I try to provide a custom Logging Mechanism for Laravel's http client:

$httpClient = Http::withBasicAuth($this->apiKey, $this->apiSecret)
            ->retry(3,100,null,false)
            ->withRequestMiddleware(function (RequestInterface $request) {
                $identifier = $request->getHeaderLine('X-RequestId'); 
                $attempt = $request->getAttribute('retry_attempts',1);

                $authMethod = $request->getHeaderLine('Authorization')??null;
                $authMethod  = is_string($authMethod)?preg_replace("/\s*(\w+)\s+.*/","\$1",$authMethod):null;

                DB::table('api_call_log')->insert([
                    'identifier'=>$identifier,
                    'attempt'=>$attempt,
                    'method'=>$request->getMethod(),
                    'url' => $request->getUri(),
                    'request_auth_method'=>$authMethod,
                    'headers' => serialize($request->getHeaders()),
                    'body' => serialize($request->getBody()),
                    'request_start_unix' => now()->unix(),
                ]);

                return $request;
            })
            ->withResponseMiddleware(function(ResponseInterface $response) {
               // How I can get requestId and attempt here
            });
    }


Logging to this table:
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_call_log');

        Schema::create('api_call_log', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->string('identifier', 32);
           $table->integer('attempt')->default(1)->unsigned();

           $table->primary(['identifier','attempt']);

           $table->string('method', 32);
           $table->string('url', 32);
           $table->string('request_auth_method', 32)->nullable();
           $table->binary('headers')->nullable();
           $table->binary('body')->nullable();
           $table->integer('request_start_unix')->unsigned();
           $table->integer('request_end_unix')->unsigned()->nullable();
           $table->smallInteger('response_code')->unsigned()->nullable();
           $table->binary('response_body')->nullable();
           $table->binary('response_headers')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('api_call_log');
    }
};

The idea is once I attempt to call the Request I log the attempt upon withRequestMiddleware and once done I log the response upon withResponseMiddleware upon each request I provide a unique identifier so I can group each time I try to call the api:

  $requestId = Str::uuid()->toString();
  $endpoint = $this->apiUrl.'/myendpoint';
  $response = $this->httpClient->withHeaders(['X-RequestId'=>$requestId])
            ->put($endpoint,['name'=>"Hello"]);

Thus I can keep a log every time I try to call the api and record whether the attempt has succeeded or not.
The question is how I can associate the nessesary request with my response at withResponseMiddleware closure?

You might have better luck if you go about it via events, specifically if you handle the ResponseReceived event (which contains both the request and response) and ConnectionFailed event which indicates that a request failed
